# template driven text field value update

Tags: angular, typescript

This is Template of cart Detail.. Am update cart quantity it is working fine ..but i need to update previous value or set if not available in stock ..

```
<form #myform="ngForm">   --added ng form
     <div class="col-lg-12 pl-3 pt-3">
                  <table class="table table-hover border bg-white">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Product</th>         
                        <th>Quantity</th>           
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr *ngFor="let cart of cartItems;let i=index;">
                        <td>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                              <h5 class="nomargin">{{cart.productName}}</h5>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      
                        <td data-th="Quantity">
                          <input
                            type="number"
                            class="form-control text-center"
                            min="1"
                            [(ngModel)]="cart.qty" name="quantity{{i}}"
                            (ngModelChange)="updateCart($event,cart)"
                          />
                        </td>
                       
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    
                  </table>
                </div>
         <form>
```

***In Ts file***

```
 updateCart(newValue: any, cartItem: CartItem) {
    const result = this.cartService.updateCartQty(cartItem.productId, newValue);
     if (result || result === 0)   //here am doid validation
      {
        cartItem.qty = 1;

      }
      else
      cartItem.qty = newValue;
    
    console.log(result);
  }
```

Here i need to check stock not aviable i need to revert back to previous value..

Is it possible to do it in  angular 10 template driven ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of two way binding use one way.

```
<input type="number" [ngModel]="cart.qty" (ngModelChange)="updateCart($event,cart)" />
```

Ts File

```
updateCart(newValue: any, cartItem: CartItem) {
    
    // cartItem will have previous value until we assign the new event value
    // To update cartItem with new value you would simply do

    cartItem.qty = newValue;
}
```

Working example in Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xujjtw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. actually if  valdation fails the value entered remains same   i.e i stock actual 15 are there if i entered 16  i have to do reset in qty in html..is it possible with ngform...thanks

Comment: You meant - Actual stock 15, User entered: 16, API call and check stock, Show error message in ui saying stock is less then entered quantity, revert user input from 16 to 15?

Comment: yes.. if (result || result === 0)  i have to update to stock value ( this am al ready getting) other wise same what user entered..i have updated ts method in the question..i need only UI should update qty //hard coded value...Thanks

Comment: pls le me know Is it possible update UI model in ng form?

Comment: @Glen Have a look at the updated stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xujjtw?file=src/app/app.component.ts